# How to convert the text typed in textarea into a link on button click?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am typing some matter in the textarea and want it to be converted to a href link on button click.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var l = $('textarea').val();
    $('<a/>', {href:'#', text: l}).appendTo('body');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/VPh47/1/)